# Войти удалено в режим суперпользователя на Debian 10 с помощью pexpect/pxssh python

Tags: python, ssh, root

Нужно с помощью языка **Python** удаленно по **ssh** поменять на ОС **Debian 10** ip-адрес.

Решил сделать это через `pexpect/pxssh`, но чтобы изменить ip-адрес, нужно войти в режим суперпользователя через **su** и ввести пароль.

Как реализовать ввод пароля через скрипт?

Вот мой код:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = '192.168.1.1'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'root'
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('uptime')   
    s.prompt()        
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('su')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('sudo ifconfig ens33 192.168.1.14 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pexpect import pxssh

psswd = 'ur psswd'

try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = '192.168.1.1'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'root'
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('uptime')   
    s.prompt()        
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('su')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)

    s.sendline(psswd)
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)

    s.sendline('sudo ifconfig ens33 192.168.1.14 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```